# Spring Boot unable to find jsp files on ElasticBeanstalk AWS

Tags: spring, jsp, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

It works good when the application is running from Eclipse. But the problem is starting after i packaging the app to JAR or WAR and running it. 
Getting 404 on every pages.
Here what i have done so far:
[image]
[image]

Here my POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>springtry</groupId>
<artifactId>spring</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>spring Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>




<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-solr</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL for JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Need this to compile JSP, tomcat-embed-jasper version is not working, 
        no idea why -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.10</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>



    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: can you show me your pom.xml?

Comment: @GippleLake i've added the pom. Thanks

Comment: everything is ok except '<packaging>jar</packaging>'. u have to package to war

Comment: I have tried to package to WAR as well. Still can get the jsp files :(
Getting 404

Comment: I don't know why you locate jsp file in resources directory. However, if you put it into webapp it works fine. I found this from http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-boot-tutorial/spring-boot-maven-example-hello-world.html

Comment: jsp files are not in resources directory. They are in webapp - and it works from eclipse only. That is the problem. After deployment they are not reachable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So to resolve the issue i have changed my elastic beanstalk from Java to Tomcat. And now it works with WAR. 
Using the Java i was not able to run the webapp

Comment: Definitely this is the way when you go with WAR files.

Comment: This fixes the issue ..i have been facing i was using Java as environment instead of TomCat.

Comment: Fixed my issue !. Great !. Thank you

Comment: This fixed my issue. I spent way too much time on this!!

Answer (score 1):

For jar packaging, the jsp files should be in src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/.
For war packaging src/main/webapp/ is good. 
Also, I guess with war packaging, you are probably not implementing SpringBootServletInitializer with it's method configure(...)  in your config main class. 
A complete example is [here](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/boot-serve-dynamic/)

Comment: So as i see both options are working on my local machine. But i still have a problem after deployment to elastic beanstalk on amazon. Thanks!